# scons not respecting variant_dir with object files

Tags: scons

For simplicity sake, I'm able to reproduce this problem I'm having with the following example...

I currently have two files, a SConstruct and a SConscript.

My directory tree is as follows:

```
- .
    - SConstruct
    - build (dir)
    - dir1 (dir)
        - mysrc.cpp
        - proj (dir)
            - SConscript
```

Here is the contents of my **SConstruct**:

```
SConscript('dir1/proj/SConscript', variant_dir='build/out', duplicate=0)
```

Here is the contents of **dir1/proj/SConscript**:

```
src = Dir('.').srcnode().abspath + '/../mysrc.cpp'
StaticLibrary('mylib', src)
```

When I run `scons` at my root directory, I see the following output

```
g++ -o dir1/mysrc.o -c dir1/mysrc.cpp
ar rc build/out/libmylib.a
```

The ar command looks great, it outputs to the variant_dir, which is build/out. **The problem here is the output location of mysrc.o**. It goes to dir1 instead of build/out. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify paths to source files as though they are sitting in the variant directory path.

Change your top level `SConstruct` to this...

```
SConscript('dir1/proj/SConscript', variant_dir='build/out', src_dir='dir1', duplicate=0)
```

And change your `dir1/proj/SConscript` to this...

```
src = Dir('.').srcnode().abspath + '/../../build/out/mysrc.cpp'
StaticLibrary('mylib', src)
```

Then when you run, you will see the following.

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.6.rel_2.3.5:3347:d31d5a4e74b6[MODIFIED], 2015/07/31 14:36:10, by bdbaddog on hpmicrodog
    engine: v2.3.6.rel_2.3.5:3347:d31d5a4e74b6[MODIFIED], 2015/07/31 14:36:10, by bdbaddog on hpmicrodog
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2015 The SCons Foundation

>> tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── mysrc.cpp
│   └── proj
│       └── SConscript
└── SConstruct

2 directories, 3 files

>> scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/out/mysrc.o -c dir1/mysrc.cpp
ar rc build/out/proj/libmylib.a build/out/mysrc.o
ranlib build/out/proj/libmylib.a
scons: done building targets.

>> tree
.
├── build
│   └── out
│       ├── mysrc.o
│       └── proj
│           └── libmylib.a
├── dir1
│   ├── mysrc.cpp
│   └── proj
│       └── SConscript
└── SConstruct

5 directories, 5 files
```